# Design question - template pattern with enum implementing an interface

Tags: java, design-patterns, spring-mvc, enums

My code is starting to look out of control so I thought I would ask for help.

I have an enum class that implements an interface. The first thing the method does is get a db connection from a pool using jndi.  Then based on the objects properties performs a series of calculations and returns a result.

```
public interace MyInterface {  
     public ResultObject calculate(MyObject myObject);
```

}

```
public enum MyEnum implements Myinterface {
    public ResultObject calculate(MyObject myObject) {
         //several steps
    }
}
```

This has been working fine with only one calculation.  I now have a few more ways to calculate with just a few changes needed for each calculation.

The template method design pattern sounds perfect for this but I am confused on how I can make it work with the enum implementation I currently have?  I don't want to add a bunch of branch statements in my enum calculate method and make it hard to maintain.

I am using spring mvc and I have a controller for each calculation that extends a base class.  I call super.calculate() in each controller and I would like to keep this the same.

Does anyone have any suggestions for this scenerio?  I feel like when I started the design was good but now I am not so sure.

Comment: Is it that you want unique, slightly different behavior for each enum constant?

Comment: No there is only one enum constant.  I just wanted to make sure that the class accessing the pool was a singleton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it really confusing that you would have an `enum` that implements an interface like this, especially if the `enum` is responsible for interacting with a database - sounds like you may be misusing `enum`s.

As for the actual problem, I would create a base class (potentially abstract) which contains the core logic of the `calculate(MyObject)` method and delegates the "additional ways" to calculate to either an abstract method or a protected method override-able by subclasses, so that you can have slightly different implementations of `MyInterface` which provide the different behavior.

Comment: As most things in Java, it doesn't work well together with the rest of the language. Enums have some serious limitations (although they are quite advanced compared to old school enums...). Really, consider converting them to real classes.

Comment: I used an enum because I wanted to ensure it was a singleton.  I read in Effective Java: "This approach is functionally equivalent to the public field approach, except that it is more concise, provides the serialization machinery for free, and provides an
ironclad guarantee against multiple instantiation, even in the face of sophisticated serialization or reflection attacks. While this approach has yet to be widely adopted, a single-element enum type is the best way to implement a singleton."

Comment: The other alternative to a singleton is to skip the enforcement and ... only create one instance.